# Switching inner single quotes to double quotes and outer double quotes to single quotes in stringified list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scrapy, quotes

I have a list of dictionaries that is being dynamically populated with data from another list. This list of dictionaries is then being used as the body parameter in a request. The list of dictionaries must be a string for the request to succeed.

The problem is that when I dynamically populate the list of dictionaries, str(list_of_dicts), it puts double quotes around the string object and single quotes around everything inside. I need it to be just the opposite, with double quotes wrapping the string and single quotes on everything inside.

I have tried replace, str, repr, join and json.dumps to no avail as of yet.

```
def insert_header(self, request):
        pid = request.meta['pid']
        pa = request.meta['pa']
        url = request.url
        pid = [x.split('ern:product::')[-1] for x in pid]

        body = [
            {"id":"1234567","variables":{"id":"ern:product::pid"}},
            {"id":"1234567","variables":{"id":"ern:product::pid"}},
            {"id":"1234567","variables":{"id":"ern:product::pid"}}
        ]
        
        if len(pid) == len(body):
            for counter, i in enumerate(body):
                i["variables"] = {"id":"ern:product::" + pid[counter]}

        body = str(body)
        body.replace("'", '"')
 
        return Request(url, method='POST', meta=request.meta, body=body, callback=self.check_header, **self.parse_page_kwargs)
```

What is really frustrating is that in a python shell I can copy the failing list of dictionaries (the list with the quotes the wrong way) and do: list_of_dicts.replace("'", '"') and it returns exactly what I need, it's just not changing like that when I run the code.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: try `json.dumps(body)`

Comment: This really feels like a X Y problem, where you're trying to create a JSON-object without knowing that there is a built in `json` package.

Comment: Thank you Zahed, body = json.dumps(body) made this work. I appreciate your quick response and if I can +1 you when my reputation is 15 then I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the line `body = body[1:-1]`.

`str(body)` does not put any quotes at the beginning and end.
So you are removing part of the actual data.

You can also use `body = json.dumps(body)` and no need any further  replacement.

to see the actual content of the `str` use `print(body)`. It should look like:

```
[{"id": "1234567", "variables": {"id": "ern:product::pid"}}, {"id": "1234567", "variables": {"id": "ern:product::pid"}}, {"id": "1234567", "variables": {"id": "ern:product::pid"}}]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the body[1:-1], that was left in by accident and have removed it from my initial post.

Comment: OK, thank you @nadapez! 
body = json.dumps(body) did the trick. I know I had tried that previously, but I had probably left in that other code from previous testing which was causing me to fail. Thank you so much for the help and if I'm allowed to +1 you when my reputation builds, then I'll be back.